# Enum instance for tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'd like to define a tuple `(x, y)` as an instance of `Enum` class, knowing that both `x` and `y` are instances of `Enum`. A following try:

```
instance (Enum x, Enum y) => Enum (x, y) where
    toEnum = y
    enumFrom x = (x, x)
```

only results in error (`y` not in scope). I'm new to Haskell, could somebody explain how to declare such an instance?

Comment: What is the line `toEnum = y` supposed to do?

Comment: It's not actually possible to create a useful `Enum (x, y)` from `Enum x` and `Enum y`.  You'd need additional context, like `Bounded x, Bounded y, Enum x, Enum y => Enum (x, y)`.

Comment: @sepp2k: When you write `succ (x, y)`, you'd want it to sometimes increment `x`, sometimes increment `y`, and somehow cover all possible `(x, y)`.  You can't make that happen when you're only given formulas for `succ x` and `succ y`.

Comment: Agreed, it seems unlikely that `Enum (x, y)` could be implemented in any sensible way just from this context -- if at all.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I can easily make that happen by using `toEnum` and `fromEnum`. Though now that I think about it, the fact that those methods use `Int`, not `Integer`, would become a problem after a while.

Comment: @sepp2k Not soo easy, even with `Integer`. In particular a generic pair instance would be hard. Some `Enum` types are finite, others not, some use negative indices, some don't. You can't write a generic `toEnum` that enumerates all (defined) values and doesn't throw an error between legitimate arguments.

Comment: @sepp2k: If you can do it, can you show me the code?  Because I can't imagine how you would make the range of `fromEnum` compact without knowledge of the underlying bounds.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I gave it a try (see my answer). It assumes that either the lower bound is 0 and the upper arbitrary, or the lower bound is the negative of the upper. Not perfect, but ok for many instances.

Comment: `Enum` is way too broken in principle to make this sort of exercise really useful, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

```
instance (Enum x, Enum y) => Enum (x, y) where
```

In the above line, `x` and `y` are both types (type variables).

```
    toEnum = y
    enumFrom x = (x, x)
```

In the above two lines, `x` and `y` are both values ((value) variables). `y`-as-a-value has not been defined anywhere, that's what it not being in scope means.

As to how to declare such an instance, I'm not sure how you'd want `fromEnum` and `toEnum` to behave, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea if you ask me, but anyway —

To make an instance of a type class, you need to look at the signatures.

```
class Enum a where
  succ :: a -> a
  pred :: a -> a
  toEnum :: Int -> a
  fromEnum :: a -> Int
  enumFrom :: a -> [a]
  enumFromThen :: a -> a -> [a]
  enumFromTo :: a -> a -> [a]
  enumFromThenTo :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
```

So in your case

```
toEnum :: Int -> (x, y)
```

but `toEnum = y` isn't even defined, because `y` is just a type, not a value or constructor. Possibilities would be

```
toEnum n = (toEnum 0, toEnum n)
```

or

```
toEnum n = (toEnum n, toEnum n)
```

or

```
toEnum n = (toEnum $ n`div`2, toEnum $ (n+1)`div`2)
```

As for `enumFrom`, your version has signature

```
enumFrom :: a -> (a,a)
```

but we need

```
enumFrom :: (x,y) -> [(x,y)]
```

what definition is suitable depends on how `toEnum` was defined; for my first suggestion it would be

```
enumFrom (x,y) = [ (x,y') | y' <- enumFrom y ]
```

---

Reading Dietrich Epp's comment

> It's not actually possible to create a useful `Enum (x, y)` from `Enum x` and `Enum y`. You'd need additional context, like `Bounded x, Bounded y, Enum x, Enum y => Enum (x, y)`.

I thought about ways it *could* actually be done meaningfully. It seems possible sure enough, a bijection ℤ → ℤ<sup>2</sup> exists. My suggestion:

```
[ ...
, (-3,-3), (-3,-2), (-2,-3), (-3,-1), (-1,-3), (-3,0), (0,-3), (-3,1), (1,-3), (-3,2), (2,-3), (-3,3), (3,-3)
, (-2,3), (3,-2), (-1,3), (3,-1)
, (-2,-2), (-2,-1), (-1,-2), (-2,0), (0,-2), (-2,1), (1,-2), (-2,2), (2,-2)
, (-1,2), (2,-1)
, (-1,-1), (-1,0), (0,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1)
, (0,0)
, (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)
, (2,0), (0,2), (2,1), (1,2), (2,2)
, (3,0), (0,3), (3,1), (1,3), (3,2), (2,3), (3,3)
, ... ]
```

Note that this reduces to a bijection ℕ → ℕ<sup>2</sup> as well, which is important because some `Enum` instances don't go into the negative range and others do.

### Implementation:

Let's make a plain `(Int,Int)` instance; it's easy to generalize that to your desired one. Also, I'll only treat the positive cases.

Observe that there are `k^2` tuples between `(0,0)` and (excluding) `(k,0)`. All other tuples `(x,y)` with `max x y == k` come directly after it. With that, we can define `fromEnum`:

```
fromEnum (x,y) = k^2  +  2*j  +  if permuted then 1 else 0
      where k = max x y
            j = min x y
            permuted = y>x
```

for `toEnum`, we need to find an inverse of this function, i.e. knowing `fromEnum -> n` we want to know the parametes. `k` is readily calculated as `floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral n`. `j` is obtained similarly, simply with `div 2` of the remainder.

```
toEnum n =    let k = floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral n
                  (j, permdAdd) = (n-k^2) `divMod` 2
                  permute (x,y) | permdAdd>0  = (y,x)
                                | otherwise    = (x,y)
              in permute (k,j)
```

With `fromEnum` and `toEnum`, all the other functions are rather trivial.

Comment: It's not enough to have a  ℤ<sup>2</sup> → ℤ bijection, since the range must be compact in order to be useful (I would say it's a rule of the `Enum` class).  Here is a demonstration of how it breaks, since `x` and `y` don't necessarily have the same cardinality.  https://gist.github.com/2279321

Comment: Instances with different cardinality are of course unsolvable, so it would only give an `instance (Enum a) => Enum (a,a)`. I found another problem with `toEnum` for `n>3` that I don't understand yet: `map (fromEnum' . toEnum') [0..]` evaluates to `[0,1,2,3,6,7,8,8,14..]`. Hm...

Comment: @DietrichEpp fixed, it had to be `n-k^2` of course. https://gist.github.com/2279399

Comment: A thought for general `(x, y)` with no negative parts: using `fromEnum` and diagonalization one can construct a `fromEnum` instance for the tuple type, and using list operations `(!!)` and `findIndex` one can create `toEnum` and `fromEnum`.  It doesn't even require an `Eq` instance (for `findIndex`) since it can be synthesized from `\x1 x2 -> fromEnum x1 == fromEnum x2`.