# How to Replace For Loops with Recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, recursion, iteration

I'm just getting started with recursive programming -- and since I've heard how powerful this is for problem-solving, I would like to give it a try on a simple decryption algorithm I wrote a few days ago.

I know it might be difficult to work out what each iteration is doing, but can recursion make this loop more 'elegant' and 'algorithmic'?

```
for (int e = 0; e < length; e++)
{
    for (int d = 0; d < length; d++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < length; c++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < length; b++)
            {
                for (int a = 1; a < length; a++)
                {
                    key[0]    = letters[a];
                    key[1]    = letters[b];
                    key[2]    = letters[c];
                    key[3]    = letters[d];
                    key[4]    = letters[e];
                    if (strcmp(crypt(key, salt), hash) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", key);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general if its possible to accomplish a task without recursion its the preferred solution as recursive calls have a fair amount of overhead

Comment: in this case loops are the most elegant solution. Try a path search in a 2D maze for recursions.

Comment: "recursive programming" is not too great in `C` because `C` compilers are not required to optimize tail calls, so you basically end up blowing up the stack. `C` is not `scheme`.

Comment: `strcmp(crypt(key,...` is potential _undefined behavior_ as `key` points to data that may lack a final _null character_.

Comment: Recursion is not any more powerful than iteration (looping).  It does afford elegant representations of some algorithms, and it lets you use the call stack instead of implementing your own stack, which can be useful.  But if you have a working iterative program then there is no reason to expect that converting some of its loops into recursive calls will be of much  benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can accomplish a task without recursion its a good idea to solve it that way. If you would like to learn about recursion check out some problems like factorial or Fibonacci. These also have iterative solutions but lend themselves much more to recursion than the problem you have here. In this case it is very clear what your algorithm is doing and recursion would make it needlessly harder to understand. Here is one improvement you could make however

```
for (int e = 0; e < length; e++)
{
    key[4] = letters[e];
    for (int d = 0; d < length; d++)
    {
        key[3] = letters[d];
        for (int c = 0; c < length; c++)
        {
            key[2] = letters[c];
            for (int b = 0; b < length; b++)
            {
                key[1] = letters[b];
                for (int a = 1; a < length; a++)
                {
                    key[0] = letters[a];

                    if (strcmp(crypt(key, salt), hash) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", key);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't disagree with everyone who has discouraged you from using recursion in this example, I wanted to write it recursively since I think it's a reasonable question.

Here's my attempt at writing it recursively. By doing this, I only need to write the loop once, since the outer loop is handled by the recursion. I've taken some liberties so it isn't exactly equivalent to your code, but I think in principle it is the same (testing all the combinations against `hash`) and shows the basic idea of how you could write this recursively. I'll assume you have a way of knowing the `strcmp` check is safe.

```
int recur(int cur, int klength, char *key, char *letters, int length, char *salt, char *hash)
{
    if (cur == klength)
    {
        if (strcmp(crypt(key, salt), hash))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            key[cur] = letters[i];
            int j = recur(cur+1, klength, key, letters, length, salt, hash);
            if (!j)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I would then call this with

```
recur(5, 0, ...)
```

to do the 5 loops you wrote. This isn't very elegant, but I think it's clear why this might be more elegant if you expanded your key to require 10 loops (and why it would be terrible for the stack at 10000 loops).

Having said that, my first thought looking at your code wasn't "recursion" it was "those outer loops look pretty similar, so I'd like to get rid of some of them." My code below isn't pretty (hey, it's late at night!), but I think in principle this would be a better approach if you think you might need to increase the number of characters you're testing to 10 (or 10000). What I'm trying to do is maintain an integer equivalent to `key` in `idx`. If I increment `idx[0]` and it is `== length` I know I need to reset `idx[0] = 0` and try incrementing `idx[1]`, etc. Every time I change `idx[i]` I make an equivalent change to `key[i]`. Every time I have a new permutation of idx/key, I do your `strcmp` test to see if I've found the correct one.

```
int ksize = 5;
int idx[ksize];
for (int i = 0; i < ksize; ++i)
{
    idx[i] = 0;
    key[i] = letters[0];
}
for (int done = 0; !done; )
{
    if (strcmp(crypt(key, salt), hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", key);
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        if (++idx[i] == length)
        {
            idx[i] = 0;
        }
        key[i] = letters[idx[i]];
        if (idx[i]) // We incremented idx[i] and it wasn't reset to 0, so this is a new combination to try
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (i == ksize-1) // We incremented idx[ksize-1] and it was reset to 0, so we've tried all possibilities without returning
        {
            done++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case recursion is good when you do not limit the depth of the nested loops, i.e. looking for arbitrary words with the set of letters.

So, the following functions do recursive search for possibility of words within the 'letters' set, return

Here is a recursive function which mimics your loops:

```
int recursion(int keyIndex, char* key, char letters[], int length, const char *word) {
  int depth = strlen(word);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     key[keyIndex] =  letters[i];
     if (keyIndex == depth-1) {
         if (strncmp(key, word, depth) == 0)  {//crypt(key, salt), hash) == 0){
             key[depth] = 0;
             printf("found: %s\n", key); 
             return 0; 
         }
     }
     else {
       int recStatus = recursion(keyIndex+1, key, letters, length, word);
       if (recStatus == 0)
          return 0;
     }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

this is a better implementation of the same function. It might not work in your case, because you need a full final string for 'crypt', but it works for finding simple words though,.

```
int betterRecursion(int keyIndex, char *letters, int length, const char *word) {
  int depth = strlen(word);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (word[keyIndex] == letters[i]) {
      if (keyIndex == depth-1) {      
         printf("found: %s\n", word); 
         return 0; 
       }    
     else 
       return betterRecursion(keyIndex+1, letters, length, word);
    }     
  }
  return 1;
}
```

and, of course the main function which calls them:

```
int main() {
  char key[256];
  char *letters = "salt or not";
  if(recursion(0, key, letters, strlen(letters), "salt") != 0)
       printf("not found\n");
  if (betterRecursion(0, letters, strlen(letters), "or not") != 0)
       printf("not found\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All right, let’s try to rewrite this as a functional program.  I’ll go ahead and use Haskell, because it’s a better tool, not for all jobs, but for this particular job.  C wasn’t really designed to do an example like this elegantly.

Let’s start from the inside out.  The inner body of your loop is the following:

```
                key[0]    = letters[a];
                key[1]    = letters[b];
                key[2]    = letters[c];
                key[3]    = letters[d];
                key[4]    = letters[e];
                if (strcmp(crypt(key, salt), hash) == 0)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", key);
                    return 0;
                }
```

This depends on an array named `letters`, the loop indices `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`, variables `key`, `salt` and `hash`, and a library call `crypt`.

I note that there's a terminating condition.  If the ciphertext is equal to the hash you’re trying to decrypt by brute-force search, the program prints the current key and quits.  Those are both side-effects that cannot appear in a pure function, and although we could incorporate them, what I will in fact do is return either `Just key` or `Nothing` if there is no match.  If the type of `key` is named `Key`, that makes the return type `Maybe Key`.

The parameters `a` through `e` are each enumerated from 0 to `length - 1`.  In a functional program, we could make these five separate parameters, but instead, I’m going to declare `Key` a type alias of `(Char, Char, Char, Char, Char)` (a quintuple of characters).

Next, we can define a list of the entire key space, from `('A','A','A','A','A')` and then `('A','A','A','A','B')` up to `('Z','Z','Z','Z','Z')`, in order.  Unfortunately, the boilerplate to make a range like `[firstKey..lastKey]` work [is a little too complicated to use as an example of how nice functional code can be,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967790/enum-instance-for-tuples-in-haskell) but at least I can write it intuitively as a list comprehension.

```hs
allKeys = [(a, b, c, d, e) | a <- ['A'..'Z'],
                             b <- ['A'..'Z'],
                             c <- ['A'..'Z'],
                             d <- ['A'..'Z'],
                             e <- ['A'..'Z'] ]
```

Note that, because Haskell is a lazily-evaluated language, it only computes values that it actually uses.  The entire list is not generated in advance.  In fact, GHC can probably avoid creating a linked list object at all.

The parameters of our outer function that don’t change between iterations of the loop should probably be parameters of our outer function, which we’ll call `bruteForce`.  For simplicity’s sake, we’ll assume an unsigned 16-bit salt and an unsigned 64-bit hash.  For simplicity’s sake, it will brute-force search the entire key space rather than allow partitioning it.

```hs
import Data.Word (Word16, Word64)

type Salt = Word16
type Hash = Word64

bruteForce :: Salt -> Hash -> Maybe Key
```

There are many different ways to write `bruteForce`, but you requested a recursive solution, so let’s write a helper function.  A conventional name for recursive helper would be `go` or `bruteForce'`.  I’ll go with `go` because it’s shorter.  Since it’s a nested local function, it can refer to the parameters `salt` and `hash`.  Later on, I’ll move our definition of the list of the entire key space inside the function that uses it:

```hs
bruteForce :: Salt -> Hash  -> Maybe Key
bruteForce salt hash = go allKeys
  where
    go :: [Key] -> Maybe Key
    -- Terminating case: we exhausted the key space without finding a match.
    go [] = Nothing
    -- Terminating case: we found a match.
    go (x:_) | crypt x salt == hash = Just x
    -- Tail-recursive case: no match so far.
    go (x:xs) = go xs
```

There is, as you might have noticed, one missing piece left.  This tail-recursive function calls `crypt x salt` and compares the result to `hash`, returning a value of `Just x` if they are equal.  In this context, `x` is a `Key` and `salt` is a `Salt`, so there must be some `crypt` function that takes a `Key` and a `Salt` and returns a `Hash`.

For demonstration purposes, I’ll do a simple enumeration of every possible key/salt pair from (AAAAA, 0x0000) → 0 to (ZZZZZ, 0xFFFF) → 778 657 857 535.

Putting it all together, we get:

```hs
module Crack (bruteForce, crypt) where

import Data.Word (Word16, Word64)

type Key = (Char, Char, Char, Char, Char)
type Salt = Word16
type Hash = Word64

bruteForce :: Salt -> Hash  -> Maybe Key
bruteForce salt hash = go allKeys
  where
    allKeys = [(a, b, c, d, e) | a <- ['A'..'Z'],
                                 b <- ['A'..'Z'],
                                 c <- ['A'..'Z'],
                                 d <- ['A'..'Z'],
                                 e <- ['A'..'Z'] ]

    go :: [Key] -> Maybe Key
    -- Terminating case: we exhausted the key space without finding a match.
    go [] = Nothing
    -- Terminating case: we found a match.
    go (x:_) | crypt x salt == hash = Just x
    -- Tail-recursive case: no match so far.
    go (x:xs) = go xs

crypt :: Key -> Salt -> Hash
crypt (a, b, c, d, e) salt = let
    a' = fromLetter a
    b' = fromLetter b
    c' = fromLetter c
    d' = fromLetter d
    e' = fromLetter e

    fromLetter x = fromIntegral ( fromEnum x -
                                  fromEnum 'A' )
  in
    (((((a'*26 + b')*26 + c')*26 + d')*26) + e')*65536 +
    (fromIntegral salt)
```

When you keep in mind that only the stuff under `bruteForce` corresponds to the code sample you wrote, we see that this code is quite simple, and reasonably fast.

So, a couple of quick tests.  If our hash is 0x48080, the last sixteen bits, 0x8080, were just our salt.  (Never write a cryptographic hash function like this!) The remaining bits, 0x4, mean key number four where zero is AAAAA, which is AAAAE.  Testing this in the REPL:

```
*Crack> bruteForce 0x8080 0x48080
Just ('A','A','A','A','E')
```

Checking a round-trip conversion:

```
*Crack> crypt ('N','I','F','T','Y') 0xCEED
398799326957
*Crack> bruteForce 0xCEED 398799326957
Just ('N','I','F','T','Y')
```

#### PS

One of the comments objected that the language I used was not C.  Now, I love C, but it’s frankly not the right tool for this job.  Your tail-recursive function would have seven or eight parameters and as many special cases (or else “cheat” by using globals and loops).

If I wanted to use this kind of functional idiom in a C-like language, efficiently and succinctly, I would write it in C# with LINQ and perhaps `yield return`.  Here is [an example of a translation I’ve posted previously](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161277/136816) of iterative code in C to quasi-functional code in C#.  And [here are the benchmarks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161252/136816) of how fast it ran.

A C# implementation might be very similar: enumerate the entire key space as an asynchronous sequence, and scan it for the first key that matches the hash with the given salt.

You could change the Haskell program above to do that, and it reduces `bruteForce` to one line, a higher-order function call:

```hs
import Data.List (find)

bruteForce2 salt hash = find (\x -> crypt x salt == hash) allKeys
```

Comment: "*All right, let’s try to rewrite this as a functional program. I’ll go ahead and use Haskell.*" ... Why?!

Comment: @melpomene It’s a good tool for the job. C compilers historically haven’t optimized recursive code as aggressively as imperative code. In fact, for many years, GCC didn’t even eliminate tail-recursive calls, and attempting to write this in GCC would have caused a stack underflow..

Comment: "*GCC didn’t even eliminate tail-recursive calls*" That must have been decades ago. For as long as I remember GCC has eliminated even non-tail recursive calls. But the main issue is that nothing about OP's question indicates that they want to use a language other than C. They certainly didn't ask for a "functional program".

Comment: @melpomene I certainly could have written it in C, but it would’ve come out a lot longer, uglier and slower. If I wanted to write equivalent code in a C-like language, I would probably use C# with LINQ and `yield return`.

Comment: @melpomene I’m referring to the optimization that converts tail-recursive calls to iterative code, which for a long time Clang could do but not GCC. I haven’t tested in a while.

Comment: So am I. See https://godbolt.org/z/g2tnJs for a live example of gcc 4.1 optimizing a (non-tail-) recursive function into a loop.

Comment: @melpomene Great! Glad that got fixed a while ago. Someone will probably clean this conversation up.

Comment: @melpomene Added a postscript addressing your very reasonable objection and giving another example.